# Ho to bridge wlan0 in AP mode and eth0 so that eth0 is static and wlan0 uses DHCP?

Tags: wifi, ip, ethernet, bridge, hostapd

I have a router that provides internet access. Connected to this router is a desktop PC that has working `eth0` (static IP address) and `wlan0`. Also connected to the router is a laptop which I use to access the desktop over `eth0` via SSH:

```
Desktop(wlan0,eth0) ---- Router(internet) ---- Laptop(ssh to Dekstop via eth0)
// wlan0 should get internet access through eth0 and act as DHCP AP
```

How do I have to configure (in `/etc/network/interfaces`) the bridge on the desktop PC, so that I can keep `eth0` static (same IP address for SSH), but have `wlan0` act as an internet-providing DHCP access point (an access point that dynamically hands out IP addresses to connected devices)?

I know how to configure `hostapd` and have `bridge-utils` installed. But I did not fully understand how a bridge works. Does the bridge "replace" all bridged interfaces (as seen from "the outside")? If I bridge, what does my router "see" (`eth0` or the bridge)?

Comment: Which distribution is used and version-name

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You want your desktop to be the AP for your network, and your router is cable-only?

Comment: @TNW Router is cable-only. I want everything as is now (whole CABLE-part of network uses static IP's) plus being able to use currently unused wlan0 on Desktop as a DHCP access point that provides config-less (dhcp) internet access to WLAN clients. Distribution is Debian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you're asking the closer you can get to what you're describing is by doing this:

- On the desktop create a bridge (br0) that includes wlan0 and eth0
- Assign the static IP address that you now have on eth0 to br0
- Setup a dhcp server on br0

The above will place everyone connecting to the AP (Desktop) on the same network as eth0 and the router.

Comment: Thanks. When a dhcp-able bridge has a static IP address, why is eth0 still static (I can connect SSH via static address), but the wlan0 is not? So, does the bridge "replaces" all interfaces in it? I mean, the physical cable goes to eth0, but if the bridge has the static IP of eth0, why can I access over eth0 from the outside with the static IP of the bridge?

Comment: br0 will be the logical representation of a link between eth0 and wlan0. I.e. the setup will be something like this: You bridge (layer 2) eth0 and wlan0. This means that all traffic is shared between the two based on the bridging rules. By adding an IP to br0 you also "connect" the PC to the bridge. I.e. the bridge now has a leg to eth0, wlan0 and the PC's TCP/IP stack (layer 3). On that (br0) you add the IP address that the PC will use. AFAIK any layer-3 information (e.g. IP addresses) on eth0 and wlan0 won't be used once they become parts of a bridge.